# Multiple routes in mvc,net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, routes

I have multiple route in my mvc application. i want to know  multiple route in a application is the bad thing for performance?

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
            routes.MapRoute(
                "Faq",
                "Faq/{action}",
                new { controller = "Faq", action = "Index" }
                );
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
            routes.MapRoute(
                "PostArchive",
                "Post/{action}",
                new { controller = "Post", action = "PostArchive" }
                );
            routes.MapRoute(
                "LogOn",
                "Account/{action}",
                new { controller = "Account", action = "LogOn" }
                );
            routes.MapRoute(
                "Localization",
                "{lang}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional, lang = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
                );

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{Name}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional, name = UrlParameter.Optional },
                namespaces: new[] { "MVCTemplateProject.Controllers" }
                );

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Post",
                url: "{lang}/{controller}/{action}/{id}/{Title}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Post", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional, Title = UrlParameter.Optional },
                namespaces: new[] { "MVCTemplateProject.Controllers" }
                );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Sam Saffron wrote an interesting blog article](http://samsaffron.com/archive/2011/10/13/optimising-asp-net-mvc3-routing) about route performance - in particular routes using regex constraints, and the ordering of routes. Definitely worth a read, especially if you consider the performance improvements he achieved with those relatively simple to implement techniques.

Answer (score 0):

No, Route checking is fast and efficient.

Most sites have few or just a single route.

Other sites have 30+ routes. From my experience, a site with 30 distinct routes has no discernible lag in performance.